# Spring Autowire byName, property name doesnt match that of the beans xml id

Tags: java, spring, spring-framework-beans

Im very confused on what the bean xml goes off of for setting up its constructor params. I am currently using the following bean configuration:

```
    <bean id="streamingService" class="com.christien.autowiring.StreamingService" autowire="byName">
        <property name="serviceName" value="Twitch"></property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- id must be spelled the same as variable in StreamingService class in order to work --> 
    <bean id="screenRecord" class="com.christien.autowiring.ScreenRecord" />
```

The class for Streaming Service is as follows:

```
public class StreamingService {

    private ScreenRecord screenRecorderX;
    private String serviceName;
    
    public ScreenRecord getScreenRecorder() {
        return screenRecorderX;
    }
    
    public void setScreenRecord(ScreenRecord creenRecord) {
        this.screenRecorderX = creenRecord;
    }
    
    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }
    
    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }
    
    public void startStream() {
        System.out.println("Stream Starting in 3, 2, 1 ...");
        screenRecorderX.beginRecording();
    }
    
    public void endStream() {
        System.out.println("Stream ending now...");
        screenRecorderX.stopRecording();
    }
    
    
    
}

How does this work if there is no property named "screenRecord" in the StreamingService.java, unless I am completely misunderstanding what its supposed to be looking up for reference. Thanks!
```

Comment: And the question is? I have no idea which question lies in this proza?

Comment: How does the autowire know how to connect to that specific class when the I'd doesn't match the property name

Comment: It does match the property name, it doesn't match the field name. But name of the field isn't the name of the property. Property names are derived from the getter/setter belonging to a field. You have a `setScreenRecord` thus a writeable property named `screenRecord`. That it internally sets a field named `this.screenRecorderX` doesn't matter. Externally there is a property named `screenRecorder `. This is as specified by the [Java Beans Specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/).